# social network of word using Levenshtien Distance

Tags: algorithm

This is a question taken from [here](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=13406684)

Two words are friends if they have a Levenshtein distance of 1 (For details see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). That is, you can add, remove, or substitute exactly one letter in word X to create word Y. A word’s social network consists of all of its friends, plus all of their friends, and all of their friends’ friends, and so on. Write a program to tell us how big the social network for the word 'hello' is, using this word list https://raw.github.com/codeeval/Levenshtein-Distance-Challenge/master/input_levenshtein_distance.txt
Input

Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename.The input file contains the word list. This list is also available at https://raw.github.com/codeeval/Levenshtein-Distance-Challenge/master/input_levenshtein_distance.txt
Output

Print out how big the social network for the word 'hello' is. e.g. The social network for the word 'abcde' is 4846.

Can any one help to come up with some logic for the same.
It is not a home work problem.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 5):

A simple `O(n^2)` solution would be to model the problem as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29):

`G = (V,E)`, where `V = { all words }` and `E = { (u,v) | u is friend of v }`.

From this, the next algorithm follows (high level pseudo code):

```
1. Create the graph from the data
2. Run a BFS from the source, and continue while there are more 
   vertices that can be discovered. 
3. When you are done, the size of the `visited` set is the size of 
   the social network (this set is the actual social network)
```

**Complexity:**

- Creating this graph is `O(n^2)` (check all pairs).
- [**BFS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) is also `O(n^2)` since `|E| < n^2`, so you get total of `O(n^2)` algorithm.

Comment: does the starting node has to be hello or it can be any thing else in the graph

Comment: @RegisteredUser: The source can be anything you want - and the result will be the social network of that specific word.

Comment: in this case marking friends of the entire input sequence will be an arduous job because the matrix or list that I will create how will I define the friend....your BFS logic is good no doubts I initially could not understand but when I started implementing this then I realized how will I make edges.....

Comment: @RegisteredUser: I am not sure I am following. Creating the edges is done by checking all possible pairs `word1`, `word2` - and checking the distance between them. There are `O(n^2)` of those pairs. The graph itself can be stored by matrix - sparse: [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) or dense (two dimensional array)

Answer (score 2):

You can use BFS or DFS or any algorithm that returns a tree cover of a graph, it is quite liaise to your taste.

Comment: I think amit's answer was enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to find the Levenshtein Distance, all you need to know is the Levenstein Distance between the pair of words.

Here you need not draw the complete graph. A better approach would be to maintain a hash table of words that you know are in the word's social network. In this way you would avoid redundant pairs. This is what i exactly mean.

Suppose the words are:
Right
Bright
Wright

All the pairs have an edit distance of one. But if you want only Right's social network you need not consider the pair Bright and Wright.

Continue in this way for all the words checked, till there is no addition in your checked list.

Comment: What's the benefit of this approach over using graph? It's not faster, and not better in memory.

Comment: It's asymptotically O(n^2). But you avoid a lot of redundant edit distance calculations as I have explained. The point is you need not compute the whole graph. edges between known elements in the graph are not useful.

Comment: You used hashset which could take large memory (for big n this wont work).

Comment: Storing a complete graph would use a large memory too. Here you don't need to make the graph just use a counter to increment whenever you add something to hashset.

Comment: Storing graph takes at most O(n^2), but saving n^2 item in hashset could take very large space (depend to hashing scenario).